# How to fix Duplicate Migration Name Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have been researching this problem on SO and google and I can't find anything that tells me how to delete specific migrations from being loaded into Heroku.

My problem was that I created multiple migrations in the same project (I was following a tutorial and I thought that I had skipped a step when in reality I hadn't) and now when I am trying to migrate this database to Heroku I get the duplicate migration error:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.7535
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError:

Multiple migrations have the name CreateUserFriendships

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `validate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:917:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I deleted the duplicate migration file in my app directory long ago to get my project up and working on my local machine, and now when deploying it is still referencing this duplication but I am not sure where I need to go to delete it.

Can someone advise me where/how I can delete these duplicate migrations?

Thanks,
EDIT: I was successful in deleting one of the migrations but am now getting a different error (after committing and pushing to heroku) when I run 'heroku run rake db:migrate':

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2527
== 20141004220407 AddStateToUserFriendships: migrating ========================
-- add_column(:user_friendships, :state, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "user_friendships" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "user_friendships" ADD COLUMN "state" character varying(255)/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:395:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20141004220407_add_state_to_user_friendships.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Do I now need to just re add the old migration? One of these migrations was run more recently than the other, should I add my original one back to my program files and commit it again?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the changes are committed and file is no longer in your git repo.

If you run `git status` in your project, it might say something like this:

```
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    db/migrate/201410170100123013_create_user_friendships.rb
```

Commit your changes by running `git add .` and then `git commit -m "Deleted migration"`.

Try pushing to Heroku and migrating again.

Comment: Hi Richard. I indeed did see that a migration was marked as deleted but not updated on a commit. I did git rm /that_file and commited and pushed to heroku. Now when I run a db:migrate I get an error saying that my relation "user_friendships" doesn't exist. See my original question for the entire message. It looks as though I deleted that migration and now it doesn't have information for the user friendships. I accidently generated the add user friendships migration twice, could it be that I deleted the wrong one? And I should have deleted the other?

Comment: Maybe an easier question: Is there a way to just take the schema in my local app project file and publish that to my heroku instead of having to run these migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do. Apparently these migrations run in order of their timestamp and the duplicate migration that I was using came after a migration that relied on it to create something to its table, which makes sense. So I re-added the original migration; made sure the newest (duplicate) migration was also deleted; and the migration ran fine.

Thanks for the help Richard.